# If $X^n$ is a càdlàg process in a locally compact space $E$, show that $\{X^n\}$ is relatively compact as processes in the compactification of $E$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, markov-process, weak-convergence, skorohod-space

Let $E$ be a locally compact separable$^1$ metric space, $D([0,\infty),E)$ denote the [Skorohod space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A0dl%C3%A0g#Skorokhod_space), $C_0(E)$ denote the space of continuous functions $E\to\mathbb R$ [vanishing at infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanish_at_infinity) and $E^\ast:=E\uplus\left\{\infty\right\}$ denote the [Alexandroff one-point compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandroff_extension#The_one-point_compactification).

Moreover, let $\mathcal M_1(D([0,\infty),E))$ denote the space of probability measures on $\mathcal B(D([0,\infty),E))$ equipped with the topology of [weak convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures#Weak_convergence_of_measures)$^1$.

Now let $X^n$ be a $D([0,\infty),E)$-valued random variable on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ for $n\in\mathbb N$.

> I want to show that if $\left(\left(f\circ X^n\right)_\ast\operatorname P\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq\mathcal M_1(D([0,\infty),\mathbb R))$ is relatively compact for all $f\in C_0(E)$, then $\left(X^n_\ast\operatorname P\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq\mathcal M_1(D([0,\infty),E^\ast))$ is relatively compact.

This is claimed and proved in [Corollary 9.3 of Chapter 3 in the book of Ethier and Kurtz](https://books.google.com/books?id=zvE9RFouKoMC&pg=PA144&lpg=PA144&dq=%22be+locally+compact+and+separable,+and+let%22+%22one-point+compactification%22&source=bl&ots=7ayJq3WXBG&sig=ACfU3U3F-cuTYkl-V1GFtUFqfpKXzOgbFg&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjr6MTDocvhAhVS3qQKHYGCBrwQ6AEwAXoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22be%20locally%20compact%20and%20separable%2C%20and%20let%22%20%22one-point%20compactification%22&f=false). However, I don't understand their proof and hope there is an easier proof available which doesn't rely on the more general Theorem 9.1 (of the same chapter).

It's clear to me that if $f^\ast\in C(E^\ast)$, then $$f:=\left.f^\ast\right|_E-f^\ast(\infty)\in C_0(E)\tag1$$ and hence, by assumption, $\left(\left(f\circ X^n\right)_\ast\operatorname P\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq\mathcal M_1(D([0,\infty),\mathbb R))$ is relatively compact. However, I don't understand how they conclude that $\left(\left(f\circ X^n\right)_\ast\operatorname P\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq\mathcal M_1(D([0,\infty),\mathbb R))$ is actually relatively compact for *all* $f\in C(E^\ast)$ (not only those which arise by $(1)$).

And even when this has been shown, how do we conclude the claim? As I said before, Theorem 9.1 is quite general. For example, since $E^\ast$ is compact, the "compact containment condition" (9.1) should be trivially satisfied. So, how can we proceed to prove the claim?

---

$^1$ I guess it's crucial to assume that $E$ (and hence $D([0,\infty),E)$) is separable, since then $\mathcal M_1(D([0,\infty),E))$ is metrizable which in turn implies that relative sequential compactness and relative compactness are equivalent. Maybe someone can elaborate on that.

Comment: (1/2) I can't check Ethier and Kurtz until I go to my office tomorrow to see what Theorem $9.1$ says but it's no problem to get relative compactness for every $f \in C(E^*)$. Our discussion on another question may have confused you so let me try to be clearer here. $C_0(E)$ is naturally identified with $\{f \in C(E^*): f(\infty) = 0\}$ where $\infty$ is the distinguished point.

Comment: (2/2)  As a result, up to this identification $C(E^*)$ is the linear span of $C_0(E) \cup \{\text{constant functions}\}$.  It's trivially true that if $f$ is a constant function then $(f \circ X^n)_\ast P$ is a relatively compact sequence since it's constant which gives the result.

Comment: @RhysSteele Ah, sure. Thank you for your comments. Would be great if you could take a look at Theorem 9.1 today.

Comment: @RhysSteele It might be helpful to know what I'm finally after: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3185888/47771

Comment: In light of Theorem 9.1 of Ethier and Kurtz, it would be enough to establish that relative compactness in $D([0,\infty),E^*)$ with all sample paths actually lying in $E$ implies relative compactness in $D([0,\infty),E)$, no?

Comment: @RhysSteele Yes, but at the moment I'm still struggling to understand why we've got relative compactness in $D([0,\infty),E^*)$. In Theorem 2.5 of Chapter 4 they invoke Corollary 9.3 and Theorem 9.4 of Chapter 3, which in turn use Theorem 9.1 of that chapter. However, these Theorems (in particular, Theorem 9.1) seem to be a heavy machinery designed for a quite general class of situations. As I lined out at the end of the [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3185888/47771), isn't there an easier proof (of the relative compactness in $D([0,\infty),E^*)$) available in our situation?

Comment: Unfortunately, I've again left my office so won't be able to check Ethier and Kurtz until Monday, but my memory is that Theorem 9.1 really doesn't require too much machinery to prove, it just happens the result has a certain generality. However, at least some of the work in that proof goes in to showing the result when you only know relative compactness of $(f \circ X^n)_* P$ for a dense set of functions $f$ and don't have a compact space but rather a compact containment condition. Have you tried going through the proof of that theorem and seeing if it simplifies in your special case?

Comment: @RhysSteele If $E$ is compact and $(f∘X^n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is relatively compact for all $f\in C(E)$, then we may note that $$f_y:=d(\;\cdot\;,y)\in C(E)$$ and hence $(f_y∘X^n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is relatively compact for all $y\in E$. Let $\varepsilon>0$. I guess the goal is to show that $(X^n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is tight, i.e. there is a compact $K\subseteq D([0,\infty),E)$ such that $$\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}\text P[X^n\in K^c]<ε.$$ Now, as $E$ is compact, there is a $y\in E$ with $E=B_{\fracε2}$ for some $y\in E$ and $r>0$ and hence $d(X^n_s,X^n_t)<r$. Can we construct $K$ from that?

Comment: I assume you meant to write $E = B_{\frac{r}{2}}$ at the end of your last comment. The problem is that it's not particularly easy to characterise compact subsets of $D([0,\infty),E)$. Ethier and Kurtz have some characterisations at the start of section 6 of chapter 3 but then one has to work out how to convert these into criteria that give tightness of the processes. As far as I know, this isn't any more straightforward than theorem 9.1.

Comment: @RhysSteele So, you think assuming compactness of $E$ doesn't really yield a simplification of the proof of Theorem 9.1?

Comment: It obviously yields some simplifications. I just think the proof technique used by Ethier and Kurtz is fine and instead of asking so many questions about the same things here you should spend some time trying to understand it.

Comment: @RhysSteele I've intended to come up with a slim version of the theorem which I could include in a thesis. If I'm not able to do so, I need to refer to the book, since including all the theorems needed is not a sensible option. BTW, in Theorem 9.4 of Chapter 3, I'm not sure if I understand the notation. Do we need to understand the martingale properties and expectations with respect to $\operatorname P_\alpha$? For example, they write $\sup_\alpha\text E[\cdots]$ in $(9.17)$, but it's not clear wrt which probability measure this has to be understood. Shouldn't it be $\sup_α\text E_α[\cdots]$?

Comment: The family of processes should be supported on the same probability space so the expectation should be with respected to a single fixed measure, no?

Comment: @RhysSteele In the Theorem they consider a family $(\Omega_\alpha,\mathcal A_\alpha,\operatorname P_\alpha)$ of probability spaces.

Comment: @RhysSteele Regarding your third comment, how do we see the converse? Why does weak convergence in $D([0,\infty),E)$ imply weak convergence in $D([0,\infty),E^\ast)$?

Comment: What makes you think they consider a family of probability spaces in Theorem 9.1? If we are looking at the same theorem, there is no mention of this, only a family of processes which is a different matter.

Comment: If the converse does hold then my guess would be that you prove it  by using a sequential characterisation of convergence in the Skorohod topology (something like proposition 6.5 of Chapter 3 in E&K) and use the fact that $E$ is homeomorphically embedded in $E^*$ to see convergence of the appropriate sequences.

Comment: @RhysSteele (a) I was talking about Theorem 9.4, not Theorem 9.1. (b) I thought we might be able to use the following: If $Ω$ is a metric space, $\mu_n,\mu$ are probability measures on $\mathcal B(Ω)$ and $Ω_0\in\mathcal B(Ω)$ with $\mu_n(Ω_0)=\mu(Ω_0)=1$, then $\mu_n\to\mu$ weakly if and only if $\left.\mu_n\right|_{Ω_0}\to\left.\mu\right|_{Ω_0}$, where $\left.\mu\right|_{Ω_0}(B):=\mu(B)$ for $B\in\mathcal B(Ω_0)$ with $B\subseteqΩ_0$ is a measure on the trace $\sigma$-algebra $\left.\mathcal B(Ω)\right|_{Ω_0}=\mathcal B(Ω_0)$.

Comment: @RhysSteele With this fact it's obvious that if $X_n,X$ are $E^\ast$-valued random variables on probability spaces $(\Omega_n,\mathcal A_n,\operatorname P_n)$, $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ with $\operatorname P_n[X_n\in E]=\operatorname P[X\in E]=1$, then $X_n\to X$ in $E^\ast$ if and only if $X_n\to X$ in $E$.

Comment: @RhysSteele Turning to $D([0,\infty),E)$ and $D([0,\infty),E^\ast)$, I think we can argue as follows: Assume $X^n,X$ are $E$-valued càdlàg processes and $X^n\to X$ weakly. Note that $$D([0,\infty),E)\to D([0,\infty),F)\;,\;\;\;x\mapsto f\circ x$$ is continuous for all $f\in C(E,F)$, where $F$ is some metric space. Now, as the inclusion $\iota$ from $E$ into $E^\ast$ is continuous, we should be able to immediately conclude $\iota\circ X^n\to\iota\circ X$ weakly by the continuous mapping theorem. What do you think?

Comment: (a) Oh, my mistake. Then sure, the expectation should be with respect to $\mathbb{P}_\alpha$. As for (b), your last comment shows that weak convergence of a sequence in $D_E[0,\infty)$ implies weak convergence of the same sequence in $D_{E^*}[0,\infty)$. In fact, the criteria in your other comments or my remark about proposition 6.5 will both give you equivalence.

Comment: @RhysSteele In Theorem 9.4, if $p=\infty$, why do we know that $\left\|Z_a\right\|_{p,\:T}$ is measurable? Since it is a supremum over an uncountable set (and there is no continuity assumption on $Z_a$), (9.18) seems to be undefined in that case. Am I missing something?

Comment: This detail isn't clear to me either though I imagine that I also miss the same thing you do.

Comment: @RhysSteele Thank you for your comment anyway.