# I'm trying to understand a weak convergence result for Feller processes in Ethier and Kurtz

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, markov-process, weak-convergence, skorohod-space

Let $E$ be a locally compact separable metric space, $D([0,\infty),E)$ denote the [Skorohod space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A0dl%C3%A0g#Skorokhod_space), $C_0(E)$ denote the space of continuous functions $E\to\mathbb R$ [vanishing at infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanish_at_infinity) and $E^\ast:=E\uplus\left\{\infty\right\}$ denote the [Alexandroff one-point compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandroff_extension#The_one-point_compactification).

I'm trying to understand the proof of [Theorem 2.5 of Chapter 4 in the book of Ethier and Kurtz](https://books.google.com/books?id=zvE9RFouKoMC&pg=PA167&lpg=PA167&dq=%22A+converse+to+the+second+assertion+of+Proposition+2.4+is+provided+by%22&source=bl&ots=7ayJrZUYBA&sig=ACfU3U29sTyUqS6p5uiXzyHRNQoEz79KNg&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjWt6e4r8zhAhXMblAKHfLyBeMQ6AEwAHoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22A%20converse%20to%20the%20second%20assertion%20of%20Proposition%202.4%20is%20provided%20by%22&f=false): Let

- $(T(t))_{t\ge0}$ be a *Feller* (i.e. [contractive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_(operator_theory)), [nonnegative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_element#Positive_operators_on_Banach_spaces) and strongly continuous) semigroup on $C_0(E)$ with [generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0-semigroup#Infinitesimal_generator) $(\mathcal D(A),A)$
- $(T_n(t))_{t\ge0}$ be a [uniformly continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0-semigroup#Uniformly_continuous_semigroup) semigroup on the space $B(E)$ of bounded measurable functions $E\to\mathbb R$ (equipped with the supremum norm) with (bounded) generator $A_n$
- $D$ be a [core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbounded_operator#Closed_linear_operators) of $(\mathcal D(A),A)$
- $(X_t)_{t\ge0}$ and $(X^n_t)_{t\ge0}$ be $E$-valued càdlàg strong Markov processes on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ with $$\operatorname E\left[f(X_{s+t})\mid\mathcal(X_r)_{r\in[0,\:s]}\right]=(T(t)f)(X_s)\;\;\;\text{almost surely for all }f\in C_0(E)\tag1$$ and $$\operatorname E\left[f(X^n_{s+t})\mid\mathcal(X^n_r)_{r\in[0,\:s]}\right]=(T_n(t)f)(X^n_s)\;\;\;\text{almost surely for all }f\in B(E)\tag2$$ for all $s,t\ge0$ and $n\in\mathbb N$

Assume $$\left\|T_n(t)f-T(t)f\right\|_\infty\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0\;\;\;\text{for all }f\in C_0(E)\text{ and }t\ge0\tag3,$$ which is known to be equivalent to the claim that for all $f\in D$, there is a $f_n\in B(E)$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$ with $$\left\|f_n-f\right\|_\infty+\left\|A_nf_n-Af\right\|_\infty\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0.\tag4$$ Moreover, assume $$X_0^n\to X_0\tag5$$ in distribution.

> I want to show that $(X^n_\ast\operatorname P)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq\mathcal M_1(D([0,\infty),E))$ is relatively compact, where $\mathcal M_1(D([0,\infty),E))$ denotes the space of probability measures on $\mathcal B(D([0,\infty),E))$ equipped with the topology of [weak convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures#Weak_convergence_of_measures)$^1$.

The proof in Ethier and Kurtz utilizes quite general results. I would like to proof the claim directly without using these general results. The guideline seems to be to firstly show that $(X^n_\ast\operatorname P)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is relatively compact when considered as a sequence in $\mathcal M_1(D([0,\infty),E^\ast))$.

> How can we do that?

(compare with [If $X^n$ is a càdlàg process in a locally compact space $E$, show that $\{X^n\}$ is relatively compact as processes in the compactification of $E$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3185507/47771)).

**EDIT**: For example, in the used [Theorem 9.4 of Chapter 3](https://books.google.com/books?id=zvE9RFouKoMC&pg=PA145&lpg=PA145&dq=%22ethier%22+%22continuous+functions+with+bounded+support%22&source=bl&ots=7ayJr_ZYzz&sig=ACfU3U0x1KVPA3ISbsqDw1592yRaNLA2GQ&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwji94Gf58zhAhVByKQKHWoCBXUQ6AEwAnoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22ethier%22%20%22continuous%20functions%20with%20bounded%20support%22&f=false), we should be able to choose $C_a=C_0(E)$ and $D=\mathcal D(A)$, noting that $$f(X^n_t)-\int_0^t(A_nf)(X^n_s)\:{\rm d}s\tag6$$ is a martingale wrt the filtration $\mathcal F^{X_n}$ generated by $X^n$, and hence the conditions $(9.17)$ and $(9.18)$ should be trivially satisfied. This should allow a much simpler proof of that Theorem.